# Real Analysis Estimate of a Lebesgue measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

I am trying to prepare for a qualifying exam and I came across the following question. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Could you please give me a hint on where to start?

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Lebesgue measurable functions on $\Bbb R^n$.

Suppose you have an estimate of the form $\int_\Bbb {R^n}|f_n|\le c_n$ where $c_n$ decrease to $0$.

Can you conclude that $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere?

If not, what additional conditions on $\{c_n\}$ would guarantee this?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Consider following function on $\Bbb R$ for simplicity:

$f_1=1_{[0,1]}$

$f_2=1_{[0,1/2]}, f_3=1_{[1/2,1]}$

$f_4=1_{[0,1/3]}, f_5=1_{[1/3,2/3]}, f_6=1_{[2/3,1]}$

.
.
.

Then, clearly it's integral goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$ but $f_n$ does not.

Comment: To finish off, note that if in addition we require that $\sum c_n<\infty$, then the conclusion holds.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo I think that's right but can you give some hint for that condition?

Comment: Let $f$ be $|f_0|+\sum|f_{n+1}|-|f_n|$, so $\int f=\lim\int|f_n|$, and use the $M$-test to justify the manipulations of the series.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but i don't quite see why it is true that f_n does not go to 0 almost everywhere as n -> infinity

Comment: @Mike As you see, $\int f_n\to 0$. But if you take any point $x$ in $[0,1]$, it's contained in infinitely many interval of form $[k/n,(k+1)/n]$, so it does not go to $0$.

Comment: ahh i see! thanks!